# Bluemix to install IBM software

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

We want to install the IBM Operation Analytics Tool. Can Bluemix provide the necessary RHL(Red Hat Linux) server and other pre-requisites such as Python,Perl and KSH libraries.

Also can we have a VM where we have these configurations and we can use it just to install this tool.

Answer (score 1):

On Bluemix you can create a Virtual Machine\ (IBM virtual Server) and install your tools and development environment(Python, Perl...). Here you can find more details: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/virtualmachines/vm_index.html#vm_index 
Virtual Servers is one of the run time infrastructures in IBM Bluemix where you can build, run, manage, and monitor your applications in a hosted cloud environment.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to do that but currently not able to di it because It shows the virtual servers beta in this region is temporarily closed to new users at this time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IBM Virtual Servers on Bluemix. There you can create a virtual machine using one of the currently supported Operating Systems:

- CentOS 6.5
- CentOS 7.0
- CentOS 7.1
- Debian 8.0

CentOS is a rebuild of source packages from the Red Hat Enterprise Linux, so if you have a requirement on RHL you can use that to install all the dependencies you need.

IBM Virtual Servers is available as a BETA in Bluemix and it is offered in the regions United Kingdom and US South. Please note that if you are a new user you must work in the UK region since IBM Virtual Servers in the US is not available to new users.

Comment: It shows the virtual servers beta in this region is temporarily closed to new users at this time. 

Do you know any contact who we can connect with and try to fix this.

Comment: Did you change the region to UK?

Comment: OK, if you changed the region to UK and are still unable to access the BETA, I suggest you to open a support request using the Support Widget. It is available from the user avatar in the upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch

Comment: I did that and they said servers are under maintenance and so not available temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Only users on PAYGO (credit card) or SQO can provision VMs. But there is no charge for it. So you need to enter your credit card information though you won't be charged for using the VMs. But you should be aware that if you use any services / runtimes, then you are at risk of being charged.